# Improving Time Efficiency on two custom List in KOTLIN

Tags: android, list, performance, kotlin, time-complexity

There are two lists:

```
val listA:List<Amodel> 
val listB:List<Int>


data class Amodel(val id:Int,var isUsed:Boolean=false)
```

> Need to update listA isUsed =true based on the int id of the listB
>
> What I'm doing now:

```
listB.foreach(){
//here i'm updating but it's taking too much time w.r.t time efficiency.
}
```

> any **GOOD** solution.

Note list size is 500k+ for simulation

Comment: can you show the full code of your loop?

Comment: Why did you omit the code in the foreach()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be slightly faster when the lists are huge:

```
val lookup = listB.associateWith { true }
listA.forEach { it.isUsed = lookup[it.id] ?: false }
```

Possibly this is even faster, I'm not sure. Because it then only sets `isUsed` in the case it needs to be true:

```
val lookup = listB.associateWith { true }
listA.forEach { lookup[it.id]?.run { it.isUsed = true } }
```

Comment: yes the second one is  more efficient thanks for that

Comment: You could use a `Set` instead since you're only using the keys really

Comment: @cactustictacs yeah, I also thought of that. But some quick testing didn't seem to make it any faster. And actually occording to [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashset-arraylist-contains-performance): "Internally, the HashSet implementation is based on a HashMap instance. The contains() method calls HashMap.containsKey(object).", so using a map directly you are actually being more efficient than a set I would think since a set is sort of a wrapper of a map

Comment: @IvoBeckers oh I meant more for readability than anything! But yeah I wouldn't expect to see much speed difference - I was thinking more on the initial setup (since you don't need to assign any values) but even then, probably not a lot unless the collection is extremely huge. I wonder if that wrapper situation does make a difference though! The compiler could potentially be smart and roll it into a single call, but I'm not sure if it does (or if it's even worth it)

Answer (score 3):

```
data class Amodel(val id: Int, var isUsed: Boolean = false)

val listA: List<Amodel> = listOf(
  Amodel(1),
  Amodel(2),
  Amodel(3),
  Amodel(4),
  Amodel(5)
)
val listB: List<Int> = listOf(2, 4, 5)

listA.forEach { if (it.id in listB) it.isUsed = true }

// Alternative to set all items, not only from false to true:
listA.forEach { it.isUsed = it.id in listB }

println(listA)
```

Output:

```
[
  Amodel(id=1, isUsed=false),
  Amodel(id=2, isUsed=true), 
  Amodel(id=3, isUsed=false), 
  Amodel(id=4, isUsed=true), 
  Amodel(id=5, isUsed=true)
]
```

Comment: Note that `false` is the default value, so you could have initialized it with `listOf(Amodel(1), Amodel(2), Amodel(3), Amodel(4), Amodel(5))`

Comment: @IvoBeckers: very good, didn't catch that. Edited it.

Comment: Does this efficiently work w.r.t to time complexity
"listA.forEach { it.isUsed = it.id in listB }"

Comment: @lukas.j what about the sorting algorithms for sorting we had quicksort.

Comment: This cannot be answered without a) knowing your code (despite two requests you have not added your code, which you claim is too slow), and b) you have not added any information about the size of your two lists.

Comment: @lukas.j     a) you are right I didn't insert it above. but  b) list size is 500k+ entries fo my simulation

Comment: @Ammar: such an information belongs into the question!

Comment: @Ammar: actually the important size is the one of listB. I quickly benchmarked it, and if listB is < 50 then creating a lookup map is much slower, when listB is > 50 is quickly turns drastically, and Ivo's solutions is the correct answer. Note that this is independent of the size of listA, it could be 100 or 500.000.

Comment: @lukas.j thank you for updating and sharing these important things here.

Answer (score 1):

How about our good buddy `Set`?

```
val usedIds = listB.toSet()
listA.forEach { it.isUsed = it.id in usedIds }
```

If you just need to know if a thing is present in a collection, that's basically what a set's for! Might shave a bit of time off vs a map since you don't need to store any value data

Answer (score 0):

```
data class Amodel(val id:Int,var isUsed:Boolean=false)

val listA = listOf(
  Amodel(3),
  Amodel(2),
  Amodel(3),
  Amodel(8),
  Amodel(0)
)
val listB = listOf(2, 0, 5)

listA.forEach { aModel ->
    // here we check listB have element of listA or not
    if (listB.contains(aModel.id)){
        aModel.isUsed = true
    }

}

println(listA)

**RESULT:-**
[
Amodel(id=3, isUsed=false), 
Amodel(id=2, isUsed=true), 
Amodel(id=3, isUsed=false), 
Amodel(id=8, isUsed=false), 
Amodel(id=0, isUsed=true)
]
```